# I have a problem with gridview display in flutter

Tags: flutter

You can see under my work, it is a lotto, a mini game in dart, user select 5 numbers and can validate his choice, the big 5 circles are the number selected but it is too too big and not render correctly in the blue rectangle :

[image]

I have a problem with the 5 Numbers in red just Under "Vos numéros", it is too big and i can't reduce the size in the code, it seems gridview adapt the size automatically, do you have any idea ?

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'dart:convert';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:flutter_app/menu_member.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_app/globals.dart' as globals;

class Lotto extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LottoState createState() => new _LottoState();
}

class _LottoState extends State<Lotto> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  var i=1;
  var nb_num=49;
  var no_select=[];
  var no_a_select=5;

  List<Color> colorList = List<Color>.generate(49, (int index) => Colors.lightBlue);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text('GRILLE DE LOTTO'),
          ),
            body:
            Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:30,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                      child : new Text("Selectionnez 5 numéros",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:300,
                child: new GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount: 9,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
                mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                children: new List<Widget>.generate(49, (index) {
                  return new GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        if (colorList[index] == Colors.lightBlue) {
                          if (no_select.length<no_a_select) {
                            colorList[index] = Colors.redAccent;
                            no_select.add(index+1);
                          }
                          else {
                            showDialog(
                                context: context,
                                builder: (BuildContext context){
                                  return AlertDialog(
                                    title: Text("INFORMATION"),
                                    content: Text("Vous ne pouvez pas sélectionner plus de 5 numéros !!!"),
                                  );
                                }
                            );
                          }
                          print(no_select);
                        }
                        else {
                          colorList[index] = Colors.lightBlue;
                          no_select.remove(index+1);
                          print(no_select);
                        }
                      });
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Container(
                          color: colorList[index],
                          height: 20.0,
                          width: 20.0,
                          child: Center(
                            child: new Text((index+1).toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                ),
              ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:30,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                      child : new Text("Vos Numéros",textAlign: TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:400,
                    height:80,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
                    width: 2,
                  ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    ),
                  child:
                    getWidget()
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:300,
                    height:45,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child:
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                    child: Text('TIRAGE ALEATOIRE'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Select_numbers();
                    },
                  ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width:300,
                    height:45,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child:
                  RaisedButton(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(9, 9, 9, 9),
                    child: Text('VALIDER VOTRE GRILLE'),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Valide_grille();
                    },
                  ),
                  ),
                  ]
              )
                          ),
                        ),
                    );
  }

  getWidget() {
    if (no_select.length==0) {
      return Text("Pas de numéros");
    }
    else {
      return GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
          children: new List<Widget>.generate(no_select.length, (index) {
            return  ClipOval(
            child: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
    height: 20.0,
    width: 20.0,
    child: Center(
    child: new Text((no_select[index].toString()),
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
    textAlign: TextAlign.center),
    ),
    ),
    );
          }
    )
      );
    }
  }

  Select_numbers() {
    setState(() {
      var j = 1;
      var num_sel;
      var pos_sel;
      no_select=[];
      colorList=[];
      colorList=List<Color>.generate(49, (int index) => Colors.lightBlue);
      var rng = new Random();
      List tab=[];
      tab = List.generate(49, (int index) => index + 1);
      print (tab);
      while (j <= no_a_select) {
        pos_sel = rng.nextInt(tab.length-1);
        num_sel=tab[pos_sel];
        no_select.add(num_sel);
        colorList[num_sel-1] = Colors.redAccent;
        tab.remove(num_sel);
        print(tab);
        j++;
      }
      print(no_select);
    });
  }

  Future Valide_grille() async{
    // For CircularProgressIndicator.
    bool visible = false ;
    // Showing CircularProgressIndicator.
    setState(() {
      visible = true ;
    });

    // SERVER LOGIN API URL
    var url = 'https://www.easytrafic.fr/game_app/valide_lotto.php';

    // Store all data with Param Name.
    var data = {'id_membre':globals.id_membre, 'result':no_select};

    print (data);

    var grille_encode=jsonEncode(data);

    print(grille_encode);

    // Starting Web API Call.
    var response = await http.post(url, body: grille_encode,headers: {'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json','authorization': globals.token});

    print(response.body);

    // Getting Server response into variable.
    var message = json.decode(response.body);

    // If the Response Message is Matched.
    if(message == 'OK')
    {
      print('VALIDATION DE LA GRILLE OK');
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

    }else{
      // Hiding the CircularProgressIndicator.
      setState(() {
        visible = false;
      });

      // Showing Alert Dialog with Response JSON Message.
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: new Text(message),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: new Text("OK"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put a `Padding` on your `Gridview` which make it scrollable

You can put the `Padding` to your `ClipOval` elements instead

```
return GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 5,
    mainAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
    children: new List<Widget>.generate(
      no_select.length,
      (index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ClipOval(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 20.0,
              width: 20.0,
              child: Center(
                child: new Text((no_select[index].toString()),
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24), textAlign: TextAlign.center),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
```